# Space in between using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 4 blocks and I need to add space using flexbox as shown in the screenshot below: [image: screenshot].

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h5>New</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien, a scelerisque neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Heading</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras conva</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras nita</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapient.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use flex-box property justify-content.
See this---:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.block {
 
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h5>New</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien, a scelerisque neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Heading</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras conva</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras nita</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapient.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is better than mine, if you look for a less hacky method, but gives a little less precise control over the margin between the columns.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little tricky but not impossible. Use padding instead of margins.
This will work no matter how many items do you have. The only restriction is to have 2 columns only.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*Set the box sizing to include paddings and borders into the width calculation*/
}

.block:nth-child(odd) {
  padding-right: 10px; /*Add right padding for odd items (left side)*/
}

.block:nth-child(even) {
  padding-left: 10px; /*Add left padding to even items (right side)*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h5>New</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien, a scelerisque neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Heading</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras conva</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras nita</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapient.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content:space-between;` to your `.container`
I think this will resolve the issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change the `width:50%` of `block` to `width:49%` its work

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.block {
  width: 49%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h5>New</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien, a scelerisque neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Heading</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras conva</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras nita</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapient.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need space only in between the columns.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  /* changed the width to 45% and added auto margin */
  width: 45%;
  margin:auto;
  
}
.right{
margin-right:0px;
}
.left{
margin-left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block left">
    <h5>New</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien, a scelerisque neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block right">
    <h5>Heading</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block left">
    <h5>Cras conva</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block right">
    <h5>Cras nita</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapient.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

try this

Comment: There is space on the right side. I want space in between only.

Comment: @athi i removed the right margin please upvote and make it as the resolved, if you got what you need

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. Here you need to require to reduce the width of `block` and add `padding-right` to `block` class.

```
.block {
    width: 48%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I added a invisible `div` with `space` class, resumed 50% div's to 45%, gave `space` 5%

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  width: 45%;
}
.space {
width: 5%;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h5>New</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien, a scelerisque neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Heading</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras conva</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras nita</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapient.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `justify-content: space-around` or `justify-content: space-between` if you want to add space between blocks.

Or you can reduce the size of your blocks like that

```
.block {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 2.5%
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.block {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h5>New</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien, a scelerisque neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Heading</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras conva</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapien.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h5>Cras nita</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sollicitudin purus sapient.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```